# encoding issues when populating neo4j with py2neo and querying with cypher

Tags: neo4j, ascii, cypher, py2neo, uuencode

I used py2neo to add nodes and relations in neo4j.

created with:

```
asno, = graphDB.create({"name":"ASNO:"+fields[8], "ASNO":fields[8]});
asno.add_labels("Network", "ASNO", continent);
```

printing in python:
        ASNO : 38023

---

However, when I query with cypher:

Query 1. match (n)  where n.name = "ASNO:38023" return n;

> > > There are no returns;

Query 2. match (n)  where n.name = "ASNO:\u00003\u00008\u00000\u00002\u00003\u0000" return n;

> > > The following is returned.

`{
    "table": [
        {
            "n": {
                "name": "ASNO:\u00003\u00008\u00000\u00002\u00003\u0000",
                "ASNO": "\u00003\u00008\u00000\u00002\u00003\u0000"
            }
        }
    ],
    "graph": {
        "nodes": [
            {
                "name": "ASNO:\u00003\u00008\u00000\u00002\u00003\u0000",
                "ASNO": "\u00003\u00008\u00000\u00002\u00003\u0000",
                "id": "906",
                "type": "Network"
            }
        ],
        "edges": []
    },
    "labels": [
        "Network"
    ]
}`

---

I need help in having the query run in Query 1 method.
Thanks and Appreciation for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try forcing your name value to be ASCII using the str() function.

```
nameval = str("ASNO:" + fields[8])

asno, = graphDB.create({"name":nameval, "ASNO":fields[8]})

asno.add_labels("Network", "ASNO", continent)
```